# Exception to Microsoft Excel Filters

Tags: excel, exception, filter

I have two cases I'm trying to filter in this database. The database in this case contains made up names. First, I filter any cell with the symbol "&". After this some cells contain various letters representing initials. The issue here is now I want to filter out any case with a single letter. I do not want to remove that letter from that cell just filter it out.

My thought is to filter out a single character except the "&" symbol.
 I know how to filter out a single character using the auto feature by
 typing  * ? *

Does anyone know how to account for an exception like this in excel when trying to filter a database?

[sample situation of some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPu9u.png)

Comment: Maybe provide sample data together with expected results. I cannot determine from your narrative and screenshot what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: if there is a max of one `&` you could set it to not show `*&* ? *` and `* ? *&*`

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column and use the formula below.Replace G1 with your first name reference, apply the formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as array calculation and drag down. All TRUEs will include a single English alphabetical letter. Just filter by this new column.

```js
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&CHAR(ROW($97:$122))&" ",G1)),0))
```